# HTTP Protocol Schema not available while creating Publication Targets

Tags: 2013

I don't know whether this issue is strange, but I am facing it first time. I am trying to create a publication target, which has a HTTP URL for HTTP Upload application. But I am not seeing any option for HTTP. There is HTTPS available, but it is asking mandatory login and password fields.

I am not sure what to do with it. Should I go ahead and modify the HTTPS Protocol Schema and make these fields non mandatory?

Please suggest. I am using SDL Tridion 2013

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion is not to change `HTTP(S)` Protocol Schema. As `Login` and `Password` is required for secured cases.

Its better to enter some dummy values in `Login` and `Password` fields. Ideally this should work.

Comment: That's what I always do - just fill in dummy username & password - this will not be sent over the network unless there is an authentication challenge by the receiving deployer. BTW, you can use authentication on HTTP as well, but obviously you'd be sending the credentials unencrypted, which is not recommended...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I believe you can edit the Schema and make them optional.

To quote the documentation on [HTTP(S) Protocol](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/concept_AEDF84FCF81F48F29A3253D1305A70B5):

> "Although the transport method is called HTTPS, the use of SSL and of
>   username/password is optional."

Answer (score 1):

alternatively, If you want a option for HTTP in your drop-down, you can create it in

Publishing Management > Protocol Schemas

use this [link](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/concept_AEDF84FCF81F48F29A3253D1305A70B5#addHistory=true&filename=CreatingACustomProtocolSchema.xml&docid=task_A8AB97C45BA54A38985D4056080BB3F0&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&eventType=lcContent.loadDoctask_A8AB97C45BA54A38985D4056080BB3F0) for more info (login required)

Answer (score 0):

Dummy values would work indeed for user name and password. The HTTPS protocol schema in Tridion works for both HTTP and HTTPS.

How sensitive is the content you are uploading? For sensitive content deployment, my opinion is not to ignore this and default to HTTP. More careful if your website and the http uploader application are not on the same server, and the packages have to travel some distances to reach the target.

In above cases a https would work better with a valid username and password. Like Nuno said, it is not a good idea to send clear username and password across the wire with http